# .How do you create a new file in Ocaml and where does it store it?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I can't seem to find the answer, how do you create a new file in Ocaml? Do you edit your file in the terminal? Where does the source code appear?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to write code in OCaml, i.e., how to create an OCaml source file. (This isn't completely clear. You could be asking how to write OCaml code that creates a file.)

The details of creating OCaml source depend on your development environment, not on the language itself. So there is no one answer.

The general answer is that you can use any tool you like that knows how to create a text file. If you like working from the command line (as I do) you can work in a terminal environment and run some kind of vintage text editor from the last millennium (as I do). If you like a GUI environment, you can run some kind of "programmer's editor" from the current millennium, or really any kind of editor that creates basic utf-8 files (or even ASCII files).

Generally the editor will have to be *told* where to store the files that you edit. You would probably want to make some kind of folder for the project and make sure you store the text files in there.

I hope this helps! If you have any programmers nearby, they can probably get you started a lot faster than asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: I was just uncertain how you created the file in Ocaml (etc, named it and saved it to a location in your memory). So you actually create the file (and write the code) in any text editor? Then I assume you pass the code into the Ocaml terminal for compiling and execution?

Comment: There is a program that changes OCaml code into an executable form. Actually there are two of them. Maybe start with the one named ocamlc. If you have a development environment of some sort, you can just click a button and it will  make an executable from a set of source files. If you work from the command line (as I do) you run ocamlc with some flags and the names of your source files, and it translates your files into an executable. (If you're just starting out, you would probably have just one source file.)